# (Problem Solving) Proving $|x|^p +|y|^p \geq |x+y|^p$

Tags: inequality, problem-solving

I have been given a problem as practice that I do not understand how to solve. Here is the question:

Given $x$,$p$ and $y$ are real numbers, and $0\leq p\leq 1$, prove that
$|x|^p +|y|^p \geq |x+y|^p$

I have tried writing down everything I know that could help, which lead me to these inequalities:

$|a|^p + |b|^p \leq |a| + |b|$

$|a+b|^p \leq |a+b| $

$|a+b| \leq |a| + |b|$

However, these don't seem to be able to lead to the desired result. If anyone could tell me what I'm missing, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The Minkowski inequality?

Comment: The desired inequality is true, if and only if, $x$ and $y$ are replaced by $cx$ and $cy$.  If $y=0$ the inequality is true.  Hence take $c=1/y$, which replaces the desired inequality with $|x|^p + 1 \ge |x+1|^p$.

Comment: Hi vadim123, I think a solution that begins like yours is what I am after, but how do you prove that new inequality? Intuitively I definitely kind of see why it's true but I'm having trouble formalizing it.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by one of the comments, use Minkowski inequality: That is, if $q\geq 1$ then we have
\begin{align}
(|x|^q+|y|^q)^{1/q} \leq |x|+|y|.
\end{align}
 To show the inequality for $0<p<1$, it suffices to show
\begin{align}
|x|+|y| \leq (|x|^p+|y|^p)^{1/p}.
\end{align}

Set $s = |x|^{p}$ and $t=|y|^{p}$. Then observe that
\begin{align}
|x|+|y| = t^q+s^q
\end{align}
where $q=1/p>1$. Then by Minkowski inequality, we have
\begin{align}
t^q+s^q \leq (t+s)^{q} \ \ \Longleftrightarrow \ \ \ |x|+|y| \leq (|x|^p+|y|^p)^{1/p}.
\end{align}